# writing in an ini file

Tags: c, linux

I'm using `iniparser`  to use an ini file for 1.Program, that create file and generate its name and this works fine,. I have 2.Program that should  "get some how " the name from the first program I 'm trying to using the inifile  but it doesn't work, here an example of the ini:

```
#
# This is an example of ini file
#
[RECORDING]

 sampleFrequency = 44100 ; # Sample Frequency 
 folderName =  RECORDS ; # Name of the folder, where the records will be saved 
 lengthInSec = 5 ; #  the duration of the recording in Seconds
```

...............
1. program:

```
iniparser_set(ini,"RECORDING:fileName","WHATEVER");// this doesn't work nothing happens not even an warning
```

any idea how I could do this.

**UPDATE**

after**jxh** answer here is what I've tried :

```
FILE *finp= NULL;
finp=fopen("initialization.ini","w");
dictionary  *   ini ;
iniparser_dump_ini(ini,finp); /// the program crashes here 
iniparser_set(ini,"RECORDING:fileName","WHATEVER");
iniparser_dump(ini, stdout); 
fclose(finp);
```

and the file hasn't be written

Comment: Did you try `iniparser_dump(ini, stdout);`?

Comment: I just did, it shows in the terminal the fileame , but when I open the ini file I don't find it

Comment: sorry I didn't get what you exaclty mean by pass it ti iniparser_dump_ini() can you write an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two functions should save and read an ini file. This example uses the working folder but you can supply an absolute path such as "/home/some-user/some-folder/some-program.ini".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// module variables
    int                 iFoundTopic;
    int                 iFoundItem;
    int                 iError;
    long                lTopicFilePos;
    char                acTopicHeading[80];
    char                acLastTopicHeading[80];
    char                acItemHeading[80];
    char                acIniLine[160];
    char                acIniPath[160];
    char                acTempPath[160];
    FILE                *pFIniFile;
    FILE                *pFTempIni;

// saveinis
// save configuration string
int saveinis ( char *pacPath, char *pacTopic, char *pacItem, char *pacValue) {
    int                 iItemLength;
    int                 iValueLength;

    iError = 0;
    acLastTopicHeading[0] = '\0';

    strcpy ( acIniPath, pacPath);

    strcpy ( acTempPath, pacPath);
    strcat ( acTempPath, "temp");

    // add brackets to topic
    strcpy ( acTopicHeading, "[");
    strcat ( acTopicHeading, pacTopic);
    strcat ( acTopicHeading, "]\n");

    strcpy ( acItemHeading, pacItem);
    strcat ( acItemHeading, "=");

    iItemLength = strlen ( acItemHeading);
    iValueLength = strlen ( pacValue);

    iFoundTopic = 0;
    iFoundItem = 0;

    if ( ( pFTempIni = fopen ( acTempPath, "w")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not open temp ini file to write settings\n");
        iError = 1;
        return ( iError);
    }

    // try to open current config file for reading
    if ( ( pFIniFile = fopen ( acIniPath, "r")) != NULL) {
        // read a line from the config file until EOF
        while ( fgets ( acIniLine, 159, pFIniFile) != NULL) {
            // the item has been found so continue reading file to end
            if ( iFoundItem == 1) {
                fputs ( acIniLine, pFTempIni);
                continue;
            }
            // topic has not been found yet
            if ( iFoundTopic == 0) {
                if ( strcmp ( acTopicHeading, acIniLine) == 0) {
                    // found the topic
                    iFoundTopic = 1;
                }
                fputs ( acIniLine, pFTempIni);
                continue;
            }
            // the item has not been found yet
            if ( ( iFoundItem == 0) && ( iFoundTopic == 1)) {
                if ( strncmp ( acItemHeading, acIniLine, iItemLength) == 0) {
                    // found the item
                    iFoundItem = 1;
                    if ( iValueLength > 0) {
                        fputs ( acItemHeading, pFTempIni);
                        fputs ( pacValue, pFTempIni);
                        fputs ( "\n", pFTempIni);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                // if newline or [, the end of the topic has been reached
                // so add the item to the topic
                if ( ( acIniLine[0] == '\n') || ( acIniLine[0] == '[')) {
                    iFoundItem = 1;
                    if ( iValueLength > 0) {
                        fputs ( acItemHeading, pFTempIni);
                        fputs ( pacValue, pFTempIni);
                        fputs ( "\n", pFTempIni);
                    }
                    fputs ( "\n", pFTempIni);
                    if ( acIniLine[0] == '[') {
                        fputs ( acIniLine, pFTempIni);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                // if the item has not been found, write line to temp file
                if ( iFoundItem == 0) {
                    fputs ( acIniLine, pFTempIni);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose ( pFIniFile);
    }
    // still did not find the item after reading the config file
    if ( iFoundItem == 0) {
        // config file does not exist
        // or topic does not exist so write to temp file
        if ( iValueLength > 0) {
            if ( iFoundTopic == 0) {
                fputs ( acTopicHeading, pFTempIni);
            }
            fputs ( acItemHeading, pFTempIni);
            fputs ( pacValue, pFTempIni);
            fputs ( "\n\n", pFTempIni);
        }
    }

    fclose ( pFTempIni);

    //delete the ini file
    remove ( acIniPath);

    // rename the temp file to ini file
    rename ( acTempPath, acIniPath);

    return ( iError);
}

// readinis
// read configuration string
int readinis ( char *pacPath, char *pacTopic, char *pacItem, char *pacValue) {
    int                 iItemLength;
    int                 iValueLength;
    char                *pcLastCharacter;

    iError = 0;

    strcpy ( acIniPath, pacPath);

    // add brackets to topic
    strcpy ( acTopicHeading, "[");
    strcat ( acTopicHeading, pacTopic);
    strcat ( acTopicHeading, "]\n");

    strcpy ( acItemHeading, pacItem);
    strcat ( acItemHeading, "=");

    iItemLength = strlen ( acItemHeading);

    iFoundTopic = 0;
    iFoundItem = 0;

    // try to open current config file for reading
    if ( ( pFIniFile = fopen ( acIniPath, "r")) != NULL) {
        // has the topic been found before
        if ( strcmp ( acLastTopicHeading, acTopicHeading) == 0) {
            iFoundTopic = 1;
            fseek ( pFIniFile, lTopicFilePos, SEEK_SET);
        }

        // read a line from the config file until EOF
        while ( fgets ( acIniLine, 159, pFIniFile) != NULL) {
            // topic has not been found yet
            if ( iFoundTopic == 0) {
                if ( strcmp ( acTopicHeading, acIniLine) == 0) {
                    // found the topic
                    iFoundTopic = 1;
                    lTopicFilePos = ftell ( pFIniFile);
                    strcpy ( acLastTopicHeading, acTopicHeading);
                }
                continue;
            }
            // the item has not been found yet
            if ( ( iFoundItem == 0) && ( iFoundTopic == 1)) {
                // if newline or [, the end of the topic has been reached
                // no config value in file yet
                if ( ( acIniLine[0] == '\n') || ( acIniLine[0] == '[')) {
                    iFoundItem = 1;
                    break;
                }

                if ( strncmp ( acItemHeading, acIniLine, iItemLength) == 0) {
                    // found the item
                    iFoundItem = 1;
                    strcpy ( pacValue, &acIniLine[iItemLength]);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose ( pFIniFile);
    }
    // remove trailing comment
    iValueLength = strlen ( pacValue);
    while ( iValueLength) {
        if ( *(pacValue + iValueLength) == '#') {
            *(pacValue + iValueLength) = '\0';
        }
        iValueLength--;
    }
    // remove trailing white space
    while ( ( iValueLength = strlen ( pacValue)) > 0) {
        pcLastCharacter = ( pacValue + iValueLength - 1);
        if ( ( *pcLastCharacter == ' ')
        ||   ( *pcLastCharacter == '\n')
        ||   ( *pcLastCharacter == '\r')
        ||   ( *pcLastCharacter == '\t')
        ||   ( *pcLastCharacter == '\v')
        ||   ( *pcLastCharacter == '\a')
        ||   ( *pcLastCharacter == '\b')
        ||   ( *pcLastCharacter == '\f') ) {
            *pcLastCharacter = '\0';
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return ( iError);
}

int main ( ) {
    char acValue[160];

    acLastTopicHeading[0] = '\0'; // initialize

    saveinis ( "program.ini", "FOLDER", "DEFAULT", "home");
    saveinis ( "program.ini", "FOLDER", "WORKING", "downloads");
    saveinis ( "program.ini", "FILES", "RECENT", "program#the most recent file is program");
    saveinis ( "program.ini", "FILES", "WORKING", "program");
    saveinis ( "program.ini", "FILES", "INI", "program.ini#do not delete program.ini");

    readinis ( "program.ini", "FOLDER", "DEFAULT", acValue);
    printf ( "%s\n", acValue);
    readinis ( "program.ini", "FILES", "INI", acValue);
    printf ( "%s\n", acValue);
    readinis ( "program.ini", "FILES", "RECENT", acValue);
    printf ( "%s\n", acValue);
    readinis ( "program.ini", "FOLDER", "WORKING", acValue);
    printf ( "%s\n", acValue);
    readinis ( "program.ini", "FILES", "WORKING", acValue);
    printf ( "%s\n", acValue);


    return 0;
}
```

Once an item is created such as [FILES] RECENT=, a comment starting with # can be added that will precede the item.

Comment: thanks @user3121023 for your answer, I was hopping  getting this done with iniparser , but it didn't work, I 've tested your program

Comment: just one question how can I handle int and double values?

Comment: I don't see any change?

Comment: is there  a way to get comments in ini file ?

Comment: I've tried to add # or ; but I didn't get it sorry about bothering you

Comment: []  ? withing I'll say

Comment: is now # the start of the comment line

Comment: it works, but only if the comment is in new line not if it'S after the value , I'm greatful   for your help

Answer (score 2):

From the [`iniparser`](http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/) documentation:

```
void iniparser_dump_ini (dictionary *d,
                         FILE *f 
                         )
```

> Save a dictionary to a loadable ini file.

So you will need to open a writeable file with `fopen()`, and pass the pointer to `iniparser_dump_ini()` to write out your dictionary. Then `fclose()` the file.

The library was apparently designed mostly around reading an "ini" file into a `dictionary`. The set and unset commands only affect the in-memory data structure.

---

Your update is trying to use an uninitialized variable `ini`, so you will get undefined behavior.

As mentioned earlier, the library is apparently designed around reading an "ini" file. So, you need to start with an "ini" file first. If you have to do everything from C code, then start with an empty file:

```
const char ininame[] = "initialization.ini";
FILE *finp = fopen(ininame, "w");
fclose(finp);
```

Then, initialize the dictionary.

```
dictionary *ini = iniparser_load(inifile);
```

Then do whatever you want to the dictionary.

```
iniparser_set(ini,"RECORDING:fileName","WHATEVER");
```

Then write it out:

```
finp = fopen(inifile, "w");
iniparser_dump_ini(ini, finp);
fclose(finp);
```